# Using R: Make a new column that counts the number of times 'n' conditions from 'n' other columns occur

Tags: r

I have columns 1 and 2 (ID and value). Next I would like a count column that lists the # of times that the same value occurs per id. If it occurs more than once, it will obviously repeat the value. There are other variables in this data set, but the new count variable needs to be conditional only on 2 of them. I have scoured this blog, but I can't find a way to make the new variable conditional on more than one variable.

```
ID     Value     Count
1        a         2 
1        a         2 
1        b         1
2        a         2
2        a         2
3        a         1
3        b         3
3        b         3
3        b         3
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ave`:

```
df <- within(df, Count <- ave(ID, list(ID, Value), FUN=length))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ddply` from plyr package:

```
library(plyr)
df1<-ddply(df,.(ID,Value), transform, count1=length(ID))
>df1
  ID Value Count count1
1  1     a     2      2
2  1     a     2      2
3  1     b     1      1
4  2     a     2      2
5  2     a     2      2
6  3     a     1      1
7  3     b     3      3
8  3     b     3      3
9  3     b     3      3
> identical(df1$Count,df1$count1)
[1] TRUE
```

**Update**: As suggested by @Arun, you can replace `transform` with `mutate` if you are working with large data.frame

Comment: +1, From `?mutate` (under details): *Mutate seems to be considerably faster than transform for large data frames*. Maybe it's better to replace `transform` with `mutate`...

Answer (score 1):

Of course, data.table also has a solution!

```
data[, Count := .N, by = list(ID, Value)
```

The built-in constant, ".N", is a length 1 vector reporting the number of observations in each group.

The downside to this approach would be joining this result with your initial data.frame (assuming you wish to retain the original dimensions).

Comment: I think you mean: `data[, Count := .N, by = list(ID, Value)]`?