# in R: make a new column that counts the number of times a value appears in one column but excludes NA values from another column

Tags: r, dataframe

This is a similar thread to this question: [Using R: Make a new column that counts the number of times 'n' conditions from 'n' other columns occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389082/using-r-make-a-new-column-that-counts-the-number-of-times-n-conditions-from)

But I need to make it more complicated.

Example data:

```
id  group_name
01  NA
02  NA
03  groupA
03  groupB
04  groupF
05  groupA
05  groupX
06  NA
```

I want to append a new column, "num_groups", to the data frame. "Num_groups" should include the total number of groups to which each "id" belongs. NAs in "group_name" mean that "id" belongs to 0 groups.

So, it should look like this:

```
id  group_name  num_groups
01  NA          0
02  NA          0
03  groupA      2
03  groupB      2
04  groupF      1
05  groupA      2
05  groupX      2
06  NA          0
```

I have been able to create a new column that is filled with the number of times each id is listed in "id", using this code:

```
MyDF <- cbind(MyDF, num_groups = c(1:210))
MyDF$num_groups <- as.numeric(ave(MyDF$id, MyDF$id, FUN = length))
```

but I can't figure out how to make the value in "num_groups" 0 if "group_name" is NA.  I have also explored using which(),

```
which(is.na(MyDF$group_name))
```

but I don't know how to incorporate it to solve this problem.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
tbl <- table(df$id)

df$num_groups <- tbl[match(df$id, names(tbl))]

df$num_groups[is.na(df$group_name)] <- 0

df
 id group_name num_groups
 1  1       <NA>          0
 2  2       <NA>          0
 3  3     groupA          2
 4  3     groupB          2
 5  4     groupF          1
 6  5     groupA          2
 7  5     groupX          2
 8  6       <NA>          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(data.table)
# assume df is your data.frame
setDT(df)[, num_groups := .N, by=id][is.na(group_name), num_groups := 0]
df
   id group_name num_groups
1:  1         NA          0
2:  2         NA          0
3:  3     groupA          2
4:  3     groupB          2
5:  4     groupF          1
6:  5     groupA          2
7:  5     groupX          2
8:  6         NA          0
```

Comment: This answer works just as well as the "table" solution, but I can only mark one as "correct". Thanks @KFB. Out of curiosity, is there an advantage to using data.table rather than base table in this case?

Comment: `data.table` is good at speed and for its compact syntax in general. Actually it's quite straightforward to understand. The advantage is more apparent when you work on large data set. Recommend to explore.

Answer (score 0):

I liked your original answer best but fixed up:

```
as.numeric(ave(MyDF$group_name, MyDF$id, FUN = function(x) length(na.omit(x))))
```

or if you want unique groups, you can easily add that:

```
as.numeric(ave(MyDF$group_name, MyDF$id, FUN = function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))))
```