# Generate a column with the number of times a value happens in a column in R

Tags: r, count, data.table

First: I already checked [Using R: Make a new column that counts the number of times 'n' conditions from 'n' other columns occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389082/using-r-make-a-new-column-that-counts-the-number-of-times-n-conditions-from) and I believe this is different.

I have a huge dataset (1,304,708 observations) containing students' scores on a test and information about the classroom they are in, and I need to know how many students per group there are. My datatable is called data_means, and I am trying to create group_size. X.2 is the unique identifier of each student (a number) and classroom is a factor variable indicating their classroom.

I need something like this third column (group_size)

```
X.2    classroom      group_size
1      09PTV0002Q     3 
2      09PTV0002Q     3
3      09PTV0002Q     3
4      09PTV0007B     2
5      09PTV0007B     2
7      15PTV0014Z     4
8      15PTV0014Z     4
9      15PTV0014Z     4
10     15PTV0014Z     4


data_means$group_size <-data_means[, Count := .N, by = list(X.2, classroom)]
```

Comment: What's the question? It looks like you have the answer in the last line. And why are you using both `<-` and `:=` with a `data.table`?

Comment: Anyway, the line that you are probably looking for is `data_means[, group_size := .N, by = list(X.2, classroom)][]`. That last `[]` just prints the output. There's no need for `<-` since `:=` assigns the value by reference.

Comment: Please check the [new HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started), especially the Reference Semantics vignette.